# Fit a image in a div as part of tile layout using css

Tags: html, css

My code for my html web page is:-

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Save Ashfield Park</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="saveashfield.css">
 </head>


 <body>

     <div class="container">
     <div class="first">first</div><div class="third">third</div>
     <div class="second">second</div><div class="fourth">fourth</div><div class="last">last</div>
     </div>​


  <p>This is testing 123</p>


 </body>

 </html>
```

---

My external CSS sheet is:-

```
 html, body, .container
 {
     height: 100%; 
     min-height: 100%;
 }

 .first {
     float: left;
     width: 20%;
     height: 30%;
     background: url(ashfield_logo.jpg) center repeat;
     background: width: 20%;
     background: height: 30%;
 }

  .second{
     float: left;
     width: 20%;
     height: 70%;
     background-color: yellowgreen;
 }


 .third{
     float: right;
     width: 80%;
     height: 65%;
     background-color: LightBlue;
         .square {
         width: 300px;
         height: 300px;
         background-image: url(testpic.jpg);
         border: solid 2px;
         text-shadow: white 0px 0px 2px;
         font-size: 16px;
         background-size: 100%
 }
 }

    .fourth {
        float: right;
        width: 40%;
        height: 35%;
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
 }

    .last{
        float: right;
        width: 40%;
        height: 35%;
        background-color: #FFCC00;
 }
```

As you can see I am just trying to fit my first image in . third.

Would I put the code in the css, to make it easier? Or do I have to put it in the html?

Comment: If you have an external sheet why would you put it on the html? Please provide a fiddle or a pen to better illustrate your problem.

Comment: Please upload to http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can review the good code and work in a fork for your solution. also take care at third and square class

Comment: first, take the `.square` out of the `.third` definition

Comment: You may have been reading some SCSS where nesting of selectors is possible, but with vanilla CSS you need to write your selector as `.third.square{...}`

Answer (score 0):

The .square{} shouldnt be inside the .third{}

If by that what you meant is that image is inside div with class 'third', it will be meaningful to put it inside the div in html

```
<div class="third"><img class="square" src="{{image url}}" /></div>
```

and specify the style of the image in css

```
.third .square {width:xxpx;height:xxpx}
```

If, not you can put the image as the background image of third. Here is the code if this is what you meant. http://jsbin.com/jojaqi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks looks like that will work, rather than a url, id I wanted to put an image from within the file is it img rather than url? For the height and width would you use auto or 100%?

Answer (score -2):

If i'm understanding you right, you have no real problem but just want tips on the best practice to achieve what you want to do-make a tiled layout using css.

It is always advisable to keep your css code separate from your HTML for manageability. To even go beyond your need and give your tiled images a great look; i'd use Twitter Bootstrap's grid system, which has the additional benefit of not only making your making your divs aesthetically pleasing to see, but also making the image grids responsive to the size of any screen. Handy not only for people not experience in responsive design, but also to experts who want to get quick results. If you've never used Bootstrap, don't be petrified. It's easy-check it out:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Have fun.

Comment: Not *really* an answer to the question. This would be something to put in the comments on the original post. BTW, how much are the Bootstrap folks paying you???

Comment: @philtune the questioner did not make it crystal-clear whether he had problems doing anything. Rather he seemed to be seeking general advice. Please before voting down an answer, read the question yourself. No i do not get paid by Bootstrap, I just use it and because the questioner is playing with divs i suggested it. Bootstrap lets you place their code separate from your HTML and you have handy classes to use out of the box. Alright i'm outta here.

Comment: Mmmm, I'd still say your answer is not addressing the OPs question directly. He didn't ask for general advice on CSS frameworks, he asked a specific question. As a vested part of the community, our intent is to encourage and facilitate quality questions and answers, not to dog people for their interpretation the questions. So I'm intending this to be constructive advice. (The bootstrap-paying-you comment was just a gentle jest. Typed with a smile. :D)